# Threadgroup memory write then read without barrier

Tags: swift, gpgpu, metal

I was looking through the project linked on the page "Selecting Device Objects for Compute Processing" in the Metal documentation (linked [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/gpu_selection_in_macos/selecting_device_objects_for_compute_processing)). There, I noticed a clever use of threadgroup memory that I am hoping to adopt in my own particle simulator. However, before I do so I need to understand a particular aspect of threadgroup memory and what the developers are doing in this scenario.

The code contains a segment like so:

```
// In AAPLKernels.metal

// Parameter of the kernel
threadgroup float4* sharedPosition [[ threadgroup(0)]]

// Body
   ...

    // For each particle / body
    for(i = 0; i < params.numBodies; i += numThreadsInGroup)
    {
        // Because sharedPosition uses the threadgroup address space, 'numThreadsInGroup' elements
        // of sharedPosition will be initialized at once (not just one element at lid as it
        // may look like)
        sharedPosition[threadInGroup] = oldPosition[sourcePosition];

        j = 0;

        while(j < numThreadsInGroup)
        {
            acceleration += computeAcceleration(sharedPosition[j++], currentPosition, softeningSqr);
            acceleration += computeAcceleration(sharedPosition[j++], currentPosition, softeningSqr);
            acceleration += computeAcceleration(sharedPosition[j++], currentPosition, softeningSqr);
            acceleration += computeAcceleration(sharedPosition[j++], currentPosition, softeningSqr);
            acceleration += computeAcceleration(sharedPosition[j++], currentPosition, softeningSqr);
            acceleration += computeAcceleration(sharedPosition[j++], currentPosition, softeningSqr);
            acceleration += computeAcceleration(sharedPosition[j++], currentPosition, softeningSqr);
            acceleration += computeAcceleration(sharedPosition[j++], currentPosition, softeningSqr);
        } // while

        sourcePosition += numThreadsInGroup;
    } // for
```

In particular, the comment just before the assignment of `sharedPosition` starting with "Because..." I found confusing. I haven't read anywhere that threadgroup memory writes happen on all threads in the same threadgroup simultaneously; in fact, I thought a barrier would be needed before reading from the shared memory pool again to avoid undefined behavior since *each* thread is subsequently reading from the entire pool of threadgroup memory after the assignment (the assignment being a write of course). Why is a barrier not necessary here?

Comment: It feels like it should work cause threads in threadgroup are in step-lock, but there is `threadgroup_barrier` with `mem_threadgroup` flag, which says that the barrier would "Ensure correct ordering of memory operations to threadgroup memory for threads in a threadgroup."

Comment: I think this is a bug/oversight on the part of Apple developers who wrote this code. I see no reason why this should work correctly without `threadgroup_barrier`. The lock-step only applies to threads in the same simd group, but this code clearly has threads from separate simd groups mixing data reads/write in threadgroup memory.

Comment: Actually, reading more carefully - you can see in line 133 of `AAPLSimulation.m` they explicitly set the threadgroup size to the simd group size (thread execution width). So in this case the threads are guaranteed to work in lock-step, but they sacrifice a great deal of compute power, as they only use 1/16-1/32 (depending on device) of threads available in each threadgroup. Still may be faster overall.

Comment: Good catch @Itai. That'll do it. It would be interesting to profile the code with a barrier and larger threadgroups. I wonder how costly the barriers are