# Incremental by kernel thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, metal

Let’s say that I want to increment a property `var incremental:Int32` every time a kernel thread is executed:

```
//SWIFT
var incremental:Int32 = 0
var incrementalBuffer:MTLBuffer!
var incrementalPointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>!

init(metalView: MTKView) {
    ...
    incrementalBuffer = Renderer.device.makeBuffer(bytes: &incremental, length: MemoryLayout<Int32>.stride)
    incrementalPointer = incrementalBuffer.contents().bindMemory(to: Int32.self, capacity: 1)
}
func draw(in view: MTKView) {
    ...
    computeCommandEncoder.setComputePipelineState(computePipelineState)
    let width = computePipelineState.threadExecutionWidth
    let threadsPerGroup = MTLSizeMake(width, 1, 1)
    let threadsPerGrid = MTLSizeMake(10, 1, 1)
    computeCommandEncoder.setBuffer(incrementalBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
    computeCommandEncoder.dispatchThreads(threadsPerGrid, threadsPerThreadgroup: threadsPerGroup)
    computeCommandEncoder.endEncoding()
    commandBufferCompute.commit()
    commandBufferCompute.waitUntilCompleted()
    
    print(incrementalPointer.pointee)
}

//METAL
kernel void compute_shader (device int& incremental [[buffer(0)]]){
    incremental++;
}
```

So I expect outputs:

```
10
20
30
...
```

but I get:

```
1
2
3
...
```

**EDIT:**
After some work based on the answer of @JustSomeGuy, Caroline from raywenderlich and one Apple Engineer I get:

```
[[kernel]] void compute_shader (device atomic_int& incremental [[buffer(0)]],
                                ushort lid [[thread_position_in_threadgroup]] ){

    threadgroup atomic_int local_atomic;
    if (lid==0) atomic_store_explicit(&local_atomic, 0, memory_order_relaxed);

    atomic_fetch_add_explicit(&local_atomic, 1, memory_order_relaxed);

    threadgroup_barrier(mem_flags::mem_threadgroup);

    if(lid == 0) {
        int local_non_atomic = atomic_load_explicit(&local_atomic, memory_order_relaxed);
        atomic_fetch_add_explicit(&incremental, local_non_atomic, memory_order_relaxed);
    }
}
```

and works as expected

Comment: Check out this question and comments on it also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66188939/threadgroup-memory-write-then-read-without-barrier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are seeing this problem is because `++` is not atomic. It basically comes down to a code like this

```
auto temp = incremental;
incremental = temp + 1;
temp;
```

which means that because the threads are executed in "parallel" (it's not really true cause a number of threads forms a SIMD-group which executes in step-lock, but it's not really important here).

Since the access is not atomic, the result is basically undefined, because there's no way to tell which thread observed which value.

A quick fix is to use `atomic_fetch_add_explicit(incremental, 1, memory_order_relaxed)`. This makes all accesses to `incremental` atomic. `memory_order_relaxed` here means that guarantees on the order of operations is relaxed, so this will work only if you are just adding or just subtracting from the value. `memory_order_relaxed` is the only `memory_order` supported in MSL. You can read more on this in [Metal Shading Language Specification](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf), section 6.13.

But this quick fix is pretty bad because it's going to be slow, because access to `incremental` will have to be synchronized across all the threads. The other way is to use a common pattern where all threads in threadgroup update a value in `threadgroup` memory and then one or more of threads atomically update the `device` memory. So the kernel will looks something like

```
kernel void compute_shader (device int& incremental [[buffer(0)]], threadgroup int& local [[threadgroup(0)]], ushort lid [[thread_position_in_threadgroup]] ){
    atomic_fetch_add_explicit(local, 1, memory_order_relaxed);
    threadgroup_barrier(mem_flags::mem_threadgroup);
    if(lid == 0) {
        atomic_fetch_add_explicit(incremental, local, memory_order_relaxed);
    }
}
```

Which basically means: every thread in threadgroup should add atomically 1 to `local`, wait until every thread is done (`threadgroup_barrier`) and then exactly one thread adds atomically the total `local` to `incremental`.

`atomic_fetch_add_explicit` on a threadgroup variable will use threadgroup atomics instead of global atomics which should be faster.

You can read specification I linked above to learn more, these patterns are mentioned in samples there.

Comment: Thank you very much @JustSomeGuy, but `incremental` and  `local` have to be `atomic_int` because `C atomic_fetch_key_explicit(device A* object, M operand, memory_order order) ` A=atomic type and  M = int. Isn't it? So I have to cast `atomic_int local` to `int` `atomic_fetch_add_explicit(&incremental, as_type<int>(local), memory_order_relaxed);`  and `as_type<int>(local)` throws error...

Comment: I think you just need to change `incremental` from `device int&` to `device int*`

Comment: Seem don't work: https://github.com/quaternionboy/Atomic

Comment: I can take a look a bit later, I'll try to fix it up